# Request to reopen "Is 'deuce' (tennis) a corruption of the French phrase 'à deux de jeu'?"

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, specific-question

This is a request to reopen the question, ["Is 'deuce' (tennis) a corruption of the French phrase 'à deux de jeu'?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77331/is-deuce-tennis-a-corruption-of-the-french-phrase-a-deux-de-jeu), as per the reasons stated in the question's comments.